# PayPal ExpressCheckout LANDINGPAGE parameter deprecated?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

In the past, it was possible to specify which Express Checkout flow (login or guest) a user would experience by passing the LANDINGPAGE parameter (along with SOLUTIONTYPE set to "Sole") as part of the SetExpressCheckout request. If set to "Billing", the checkout experience would default to guest checkout, whereas if set to "Login", the user would be asked to authenticate with their PayPal account.

PayPal appears to be experimenting with a new Express Checkout UI, which does not honor the LANDINGPAGE parameter; even if Billing is passed, the login flow is dispatched in the interface.

Is there a way to force display guest checkout in the new Express Checkout UI on redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're fixing that as we speak. `LANDINGPAGE` will continue to work for you after this.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks Robert! Do you have an estimate on when this will be resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment; once I found out, I'll update this answer for you.

Comment: Hi Robert - I hope you've had a pleasant start to the New Year. I'm wondering if you can share an update on when the landing page parameter will be implemented in the new Express Checkout payment flow? Those customers who are presented with the new flow and are expecting to see a credit card page based on their selection within our cart prior to the redirect to PayPal are often times confused and do not recognize the "Checkout as Guest" option. Any timeline you can share is greatly appreciated! Happy New Year!