# PayPal Permissions API - Set Header Image

Tags: paypal, paypal-permissions

The PayPal Express checkout API has a request parameter for setting a header image to be displayed as part of the checkout flow.

I am currently working on building out the Permissions API, and have noticed that my authentication screen does not display a header image. Browsing through the documentation, I do not see an option for setting this. Could someone please tell me how I can incorporate a header image in the PayPal Permissions API requestPermissions web flow?

Please see a screenshot of the permissions flow I am seeing here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrH77.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up Custom Payment Pages in your PayPal profile?

Comment: Yes I have, both banner and logo are set, and the custom payment page style is set as the primary page style. The previews for both classic and enhanced styles show the graphics. In the permissions flow, however, the header still does not populate. This is on a live business account.

Comment: My samples are from the old permissions API, and it's apparently still using the old landing pages for things which still work when passing the header in the API request.  They recently launched this new set of landing pages, though, and I know there are some things like banner headers not working with those.  Can you include a screen shot of what you're getting.  Maybe I can confirm that you are or aren't seeing the new pages.

Comment: I edited the original post and provided a link. I'll continue digging through the API docs as well. I did not see an option for passing a header, but will keep looking. The ExpressCheckout "imgHdr" param did not work for me. Which param are you using to set a header?

Comment: https:\//svcs.paypal.com/Permissions/GetPermissions - I am not specifying an API version, therefore per documentation should be latest

Comment: Redirect URL is: https:\//www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=<REQUEST_TOKEN>

Comment: Ok, yeah, that looks like you're using the new permissions API which is part of the Adaptive Payments platform.  The one I'm using is the very first one they released, which I'm not even sure ever made it out of beta before they moved to the other one.  The one I'm using isn't token based like the new one is.  Unfortunately, it looks like one of those instances where the new version lacks some of the functionality of the old one.